# Check if HDMI port is damaged

Tags: 16.04, hdmi, xrandr, external-monitor

I've been using my laptop connected to an external monitor and suddenly when I connect my monitor to my laptop the monitor says there is no HDMI signal.

I would like to know if there is anyway to find out if my HDMI port is damaged. I ask this question because when I run xrandr I do not see a setting for HDMI. Would this imply the HDMI is disconnected?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to boot using a disk or a USB with Ubuntu. 
If your HDMI port works from live support then maybe you had a problem with your driver.

Answer (score 0):

well let me ask a question first, did you try using a different cable?
if the problem still persists then there is one of two things going on 

one the monitor HDMI port broke
two the laptop HDMI port broke
you can simply test this by trying a different display or try plugging the display into something else

Comment: Thanks delfiler you're right, but that was going to be my next step after I verified that the port is working then figure out if its the cord or monitor.

Comment: @ToddMatsumoto well if you ask me it is a bit silly to do so when you can already verify if it might be the cord or monitor, at least i amuse you have a desktop, so you know where the problem might be instead of waiting on a way to verify you can verify it with my suggested methodes